# How to connect matterjs to html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, matter.js

I have recently downloaded matterjs using npm using the command npm install matter-js.

I use vscode for my html project. I have a folder called Node. And another folder ( which is automatically generated ) called node-modules.

> The folder node-modules is **not** inside Node folder.

The matter-js module is present inside node-modules.

Now inside my Node folder I created a file called index.html and added this line

```
<script src="matter.js"></script>
```

When I start doing my program in the script tag and then tried to run. The console shows that it could not find matter.js file.

What should I do now in order to **embed** the matter.js module to my html program?

Even in the matterjs docs it was just mentioned to install using npm and then use it in you html.  I have done as it is mentioned and still unable to connect.

Comment: You should be able to follow the guide from `matter.js`'s website on how to install and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CDN in HTML follow  this web site `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/matter-js`

or you can add this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.1/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-3CP+e7z5ieYYTIyvRvV3eGVYR67yXg5V2mWfg8pEJJd2mlh8tG/cnDv5scTmRztEYHTksBlpPOmxFOiMtHfZdQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```